# REST related query- for use in Java web app

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am trying to create a REST API using Java.

Now, for the front end, I am using socialauth, so that facebook/twitter/yahoo/hotmail/gmail users can sign in to the application.

After a user is signed in, he should be able to access the data for his account- I want to create a REST API that enables each user to access his data. I have understood the basics of creating a REST API using Jersey framework, however how do I ensure that only a user who is correctly logged in to the application, can access data via the REST API?

What I thought of is, I will store the user's email ID in session, when he logs in. And whenever he makes a request to the API, the email ID in session is passed as a input parameter to the REST API, and the REST API checks that data is asked for same email ID, as the email ID parameter.

Is the above way of thinking correct? What is the recommended/best way to implement REST API in the scenario as given above?